# code signing exists in project build settings but not in target Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

Well I am trying to upload my first app in IOS.

I have done these steps correctly.

1 - I verified that my new app is in "Waiting for Upload" state.

2 - I have download and double click on the WWDR intermediate certificate. Verified that this exist in my key chains.

3 - I verified that my distribution certificatate is not expired. It's expiration date is a year from today. Its status is "Issued"

4 - I have created app id. I verified that the app name space portion is exactly the same as my application name space. The states that this app is in are: - push notification: configurable (yellow) - in app purchase: enable (green) (i want to turn this off, but there's no way to) - game center: enable (green) (i want to turn this off, but there's now way to) - iCloud: configurable (yellow)

5 - I have verified that my distribution provision is "Active" for the correct application id.

6 - i have downloaded and installed and installed all 3 where they belong: a - WWDR intermediate certificate b - Distribution certificate c - Distribution provisioning profile

i declared my app id in ios provisioning portal to be `com.mycompany.app` but it added a number in front of it. so in the certificate I do see something like this: `QWER1234.com.mycompany.app`

Now in Xcode 4.5 I am searching for code signing in build settings for project and I do set it at my certificate.

**But for the target, If I search for code signing in build settings, i do not find anything. Not that I do not assign the correct certificate, I just cannot find  anything.**

You can see it in the image below:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried switching from "Basic" to "All" when you view the build settings? I think that when set to "Basic" you will not see the code signing options. You can see the setting on the left side of your screenshot.